# Audio recording issue in oppo phone voice to text working in other devices fine both audio recording and voice to text

Tags: android, text, voice, mediarecorder

'calling the start after prepare method as suggested in android official docs'
...
try {
mediaRecorder?.prepare()
mediaRecorder?.start()

```
             } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
             }
          ...
```

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you mean by _"issue"_.

Comment: Checkpermission media_record-code =8 
MediaRecorder Start failed -38 android
OppoMmLogWriter mediaRecorder fail 201
des AV_RecordException

Comment: Granted the AUDIO_RECORD and STORAGE Read and Write permission too any suggestions or any reference will be helpful